# product of log-normal variables

Tags: probability, distributions, simulation, lognormal-distribution

I'm trying to figure out some "paradox" that I don't understand.
I want to model the evolution of some quantity (eg price), my assumption is that from one time step to the next, I will multiply this quantity by some random variable that is from a log-normal distribution, with mean 1.
However after several time steps, I always get something very close to 0.
What I am missing ? I'm thinking the expected value at time n should be the initial expected value. So I would expect that the value at time n is reasonably close to the initial value (or same magnitude)
Here's a python snippet to explain:

```py
    variance = 0.5
    mu = - variance / 2
    data = [math.exp(np.random.normal(mu, math.sqrt(variance))) for _ in range(100)]
    np.mean(data), np.product(data)
 (1.0281333043113792, 1.6729502153887247e-08)
```

On lots of retry I always get something similar : the average is 1 (as expected), but the product becomes very small.

What am I missing here ?
Alternatively how could I simply model the evolution of this quantity if I want it to change but keep the same expectation across time ?

Comment: The product is not comparable to the mean in any respect: in particular, the mean sums the values *and then divides by 100,* while the product merely multiplies everything.  To make any reasonable comparison you should take the 100th root of the product.  Its value, $0.836,$ estimates the geometric mean $\exp(\mu)=0.882.$ This says your model is, on average, reducing a running (geometric) mean by 12% on each step.  It's no wonder that after 100 such reductions you wind up near zero!

Comment: @whuber thanks
what I don't get is why this product of 100 RV is always that small. Its mean (of the product) should be 1 right ?

Comment: No: the *arithmetic* mean should be near $1.$  The *geometric mean* should be $\exp(\mu).$  You cannot have both means near $1$ unless there's practically no variance.

Comment: @whuber each random variable has expectation 1, I'm evaluating the product of 100 independent random variable with expectation 1.... shouldnt the expectation be 1 too ?

Comment: Yes: the expectation is an *arithmetic mean*. Any non-constant positive random variable with expectation $\mu$ will have a *geometric mean* strictly less than $\mu.$  See for yourself: consider a Binomial variable with equal chances of $1/2$ and $3/2.$ Its expectation is $1.$  In a sufficiently long independent sequence of $n$ values about $n/2$ of the outcomes will be $1/2$ and the other $n/2$ will be $3/2,$ for an average of $[(1/2)^{n/2}(3/2)^{n/2}]^{1/n}=\sqrt{3}/2\approx 0.866.$

Comment: If you had $50$ copies of $1.625$ and $50$ copies of $0.425$ then their mean would be $1.025$ while their product would be about $10^{-8}$, similar to your result.  In your log-normal code, if you wanted about half your simulated products to be below $1$ and half above $1$, i.e. have a median of $e^{\mu}=1$, then you want your `mu` to be $0$ rather than $-0.25$

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the product of simulated log normal prices that are centered at 1. The issue is some of these values even after exponentiation are very close to zero.

To see what is happening I suggest printing the 100 values of the data array out, so that you can see the smaller values that are causing the issue.

One question I have is why are taking a the product of 100 random log normal variates?

Comment: >One question I have is why are taking a the product of 100 random log normal variates?
I'm simulating the evolution of a quantity, where the value at time t+1 is the value at time t multiplied by a log-normal variable, with mean 1.
What I dont understand is why I see the mean reducing over time, when I'm always just multiplying by a value of mean 1